# resolv.conf not updated to failover network when primary network goes down

Tags: router, dns, failover

I'm running Debian 10 with two 4G connections: main via wifi `wlan0` and failover on `enp0s6f1u2`.

The connections are being masqueraded to the local network on `eth0` running `dndmasq`.

The IP address of the gateway on `wlan0` appears in `resolv.conf` and it is indeed a nameserver.

However, when `wlan0` goes down `resolv.conf` is not updated and therefore all DNS requests fail; it should be the IP address of the gateway on `enp0s6f1u2`.

As a workaround I have added

```
server=8.8.8.8
```

to `dnsmasq.conf`.

I tried adding

```
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8
```

to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` but it didn't do anything.

So what's wrong?
Why when `wlan0` goes down does it's gateway's IP remain in `resolf.conf`?

Comment: Does the actual Wi-Fi link go down, or only the Internet access through that link?

Comment: The wifi link is terminated and `wlan0` goes down. (What actually happens is that the gateway, which is an Adroid phone, leaves the premises.)